# How does the following truth table show Y's behaviour?

Tags: boolean-algebra

a       b       c   Y
0       0       0   0
0       0       1   1
0       1       0   0
0       1       1   1
1       0       0   1
1       0       1   1
1       1       1   0
1       1       0   0

How would you put this into a logical expression that shows Y's behaviour?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual problems but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: try karnaugh table

Answer (score 4):

Giving an example of what **Eugene** has said, but letting you do your own homework. Let's look at another Truth Table:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a& b & c & \varphi \\ \hline
1 & 1& 1& 1\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

To put it on **DNF** just look at the rows which evaluate to **True**.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a& b & c & \varphi &  \\ \hline
1 & 1& 1& 1 & a \wedge b \wedge c \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1& a \wedge b \wedge \lnot c \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1& a \wedge \lnot b \wedge \lnot c \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& \lnot a \wedge b \wedge \lnot c \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& \lnot a \wedge \lnot b \wedge \lnot c \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

So the **DNF** of $\varphi$ is : $$ (a \wedge b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge b \wedge \lnot c) \vee (a \wedge \lnot b \wedge \lnot c) \vee (\lnot a \wedge b \wedge \lnot c) \vee (\lnot a \wedge \lnot b \wedge \lnot c) $$

To put it on **CNF** just look at the rows which evaluate to **False**. Now just negate those rows to get **True**.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a& b & c & \varphi & & & \lnot \varphi & \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a \wedge \lnot b \wedge c & & 1 & \lnot a \vee b \vee \lnot c\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \lnot a \wedge b \wedge c & & 1 & a \vee \lnot b \vee \lnot c\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \lnot a \wedge \lnot b \wedge c & & 1 & a \vee b \vee \lnot c\\ \hline
\end{array}
$

So the **CNF** of $\varphi$ is:

$$ (\lnot a \vee b \vee \lnot c) \wedge (a \vee \lnot b \vee \lnot c) \wedge (a \vee b \vee \lnot c) $$

Answer (score 1):

You can write either CNF or DNF from the truth table directly and then transform it to any form you like opening brackets and possibly using absorption rule.

Answer (score 0):

## Define `Y` as:

```
|&A!B&C!A
```

If you can't understand it, then here is a more readable version:

```
Y = (((A) AND (NOT B)) OR ((C) AND (NOT A)))
```

## Explanation

If either:

- A = 1 and B = 0
- C = 1 and A = 0

Then Y = 1. Else, Y = 0.

Comment: I'd describe infix as "more readable". Calling it "more basic" suggests that it's only needed by people who aren't smart enough to parse Polish notation. Frankly, life's too short to unpick that string of symbols.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "more basic" was referring to the complexity of the polish-notation-mess-that-I-might-have-alerady-forgot-so-you-need-to-make-a-parser-to-even-get-anything-out-of-it. But, it is a shorter notation. Ikr, life's **so short**.